# Trigger email response from condition questionnaire

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I am having a hard time creating an App script. I look at example and reference, but it is hard to create a trigger response from the google forms questins.

For example:

Are you interested in receiving a free day pass session?

- [] Yes
- [] NO

If the user select yes then after submitting the form, document will send an email to the user

or

If the user select no then after submitting the form, document will express something different form to the user email.

Allow me to send you my survey: https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1jgNcswV6xdNtfYDPVofpcKpmRnrEj8jg_DljPCzmxIo/prefill

I have two email trigger response for my user:

1. Are you interested in receiving a free day pass session? *
   A. "yes" create a new document response
   B. "No"  Create a new document response
2. Support our Fitness Community

Can someone show me the correct method by using the refer documentations form [Google APP Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support)

Answer (score 1):

```
function ToSendOrNotToSend(e){
  //Logger.log(JSON.stringify(e));
  if(e.namedValues.One[0]=='Yes') {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(e.namedValues['Email Address'],'test subject','test message');
  }
}
```

Form:

[image]

The Trigger:

[image]